# Getting ANR report from Google Console with crashlytics-2.10.1

Tags: java, android, crashlytics, google-fabric

We're using this config :

answers-1.4.6.aar,beta-1.2.10.aar, crashlytics-2.10.1.aar, crashlytics-core-2.6.7.aar, crashlytics-ndk, 2.1.0.aar, fabric-1.4.7.aar

And getting this ANR log :

> "Crashlytics Exception Handler1" tid=32 Waiting "Crashlytics Exception
>   Handler1" prio=5 tid=32 Waiting | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0
>   flags=1 obj=0x14242468 self=0x787b380800 | sysTid=11718 nice=10
>   cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x78689c64f0 | state=S schedstat=(
>   84559469 206904789 417 ) utm=4 stm=4 core=1 HZ=100 |
>   stack=0x78688c3000-0x78688c5000 stackSize=1041KB | held mutexes=
>
> at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method) waiting on <0x022a44fe> (a
>   java.lang.Object) at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$ (Thread.java:2137)
>   locked <0x022a44fe> (a java.lang.Object) at sun.misc.Unsafe.park
>   (Unsafe.java:358) at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park
>   (LockSupport.java:190) at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await
>   (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2059) at
>   java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take
>   (LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask
>   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
>   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
>   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) at
>   io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun
>   (ExecutorUtils.java:75) at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.g.run
>   (BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30) at java.lang.Thread.run
>   (Thread.java:764)

Comment: Did you find any solution to it?